# Maven exec-plugin pom.xml definition: activate shell interpretation for characters

Tags: java, shell, plugins, maven, character

I use the Maven plugin exec and have defined it in a profile of my pom.xml like this:

```
<profile>
    <id>optimizepng</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>optipng</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>src/main/webapp/images/*.png</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Now, if I set the argument that I defined in this code sample to `<argument>-h</argument>`, the terminal call `mvn org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:exec -P optimizepng` works as expected and prints out the help of optipng.

What I figured out is, that the asterisk may not be interpreted as a shell character. Could this be the reason for it? If so, is there a tag that I can apply anywhere to toggle shell interpretation?

Additional info on my plan in the first place:
I want to optimize all png files in the src/main/webapp/images/ folder, using optipng. What I would use as a shell command is `optipng src/main/webapp/images/*.png`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, now that was quick. I figured out, I could just start the shell instead and let it interpret the terminal call I want to execute.

```
<configuration>
    <executable>sh</executable>
    <arguments>
        <argument>-c</argument>
        <argument>optipng src/main/webapp/images/*.png</argument>
    </arguments>
</configuration>
```

This code sample is what I had to fix, so this does the job.